# Not mutating trees in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm currently teaching myself Haskell; let us say, purely for the sake of argument, that I'm writing a compiler in Haskell. I have an AST, defined with something like:

```
data Node =
      Block { contents :: [Node], vars :: Map String Variable }
    | VarDecl { name :: String }
    | VarAssign { name :: String, value :: Node, var :: Variable }
    | VarRef { name :: String, var :: Variable }
    | Literal { value :: Int }
```

Each `Block` is a stack frame. I wish to resolve all the variable references.

In a world with mutable data, the way I'd do this is:

- walk the tree keeping track of the most recent `Block` looking for `VarDecl` nodes; at each one, I'd add a `Variable` to the closest `Block`.
- walk the tree again, looking for `VarAssign` and `VarRef` nodes. Each time I see one, I'd look the variable up in the stack frame chain and annotate the AST node with the corresponding `Variable`.

Now, whenever I'm doing work on the tree, and come across a `VarRef`, I know precisely which `Variable` is actually being referred to.

Of course, in Haskell I'd need a different approach, due to the tree not being mutable. The naive approach is to rewrite the tree.

```
declareVariables Block contents _ = Block {
    contents = declareVariables contents,
    vars = createVariablesFor (findVariablesInBlock contents) }
declareVariables VarAssign name value var =
    VarAssign name (declareVariables value) var
declareVariables Literal i = Literal i
...etc...

findVariablesInBlock VarDecl name = [name]
findVariablesInBlock Block contents _ = []
findVariablesInBlock VarAssign name value _ =
    findVariablesInBlock value
...etc...
```

(All code completely untested and purely for illustrative purposes.)

But this is pretty gruesome; I end up walking the tree twice, once to find `Block`s and once to find `VarDecl`s, and there's an awful lot of boilerplate. Plus, given that a `Variable` isn't mutable, there's a limited amount of use to annotating all my nodes with one in the first place --- I can't usefully annotate the `Variable` without rewriting the whole tree again.

Alternative A: I could make everything mutable. Now I've got a tree of `STRef`s and everything has to live inside the `ST` monad. As a side effect, my code smells.

Alternative B: don't try to store everything in the same data structure. Have completely separate storage of `StackFrame` and `Variable` structures, and build these when I walk the tree, leaving the AST untouched. Except that this means I can't easily map from a `VarRef` to a `Variable`, which was the whole point of the exercise. I could create a `Data.Map VarRef Variable` lookup table... but that's gruesome, too.

What's a good Haskell-idiom way of solving this kind of problem?

Comment: well you usually you take the environment (where variables/values/... are bound) with you on each (usually recursive) call ;) - but there are plenty tutorials on this around

Comment: I should add that I'm not trying to _actually_ write a compiler; it was just the simplest example of the kind of problem which I'm trying to solve.

Comment: still the same - if you don't want to go into the state/reader-monad (yet) you should just make those dependencies into parameters and pass them around - FP 101 ;)

Comment: @Carsten Why "infamous"?

Comment: @Jubobs you are right that's unfair of me - **sorry** (I was thinking of the claim - I never managed to do it in 48 hours ;)

Comment: @Carsten No problem! You're entitled to your opinions `:)` I was just curious  as to why you though it was "infamous".

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this (as with your code, it is completely untested and intended only for illustrative purposes):

```
data Node var
    = Block { contents :: [Node] }
    | VarDecl { name :: var }
    | VarAssign { name :: var, value :: Node }
    | VarRef { name :: var }
    | Literal { value :: Int }
```

The idea of the above type is that AST nodes are parameterized by what information they store about variables. After a mere parse, they will store just variable names (so have type `Node String`); then there will be a name resolution phase that converts them to references of some other kind (so produce type `Node Variable`). Thus:

```
data GenVar a
genVar :: String -> GenVar Variable
genVar = undefined

type Environment = Map String Variable
resolveNames :: Environment -> Node String -> MaybeT GenVar (Node Variable)
resolveNames env ast = case ast of
    VarDecl   name       -> mzero -- variable declarations serve no purpose after all variables have been resolved
    VarAssign name value -> VarAssign <$> lookup name env <*> pure value
    VarRef    name       -> VarRef    <$> lookup name env
    Literal        value -> Literal   <$>                     pure value
    Block contents -> do
        vars <- mapM (lift . genVar) names
        -- union is left-biased, so this will overwrite old variables
        -- (if your language can refer to outer scopes, you will need
        -- a more exciting environment like [Map String Variable])
        let env' = fromList (zip names vars) `union` env
        Block <$> mapM (resolveNames env') stmts
        where
        (decls, stmts) = partition isDecl contents
        names = map name decls

isDecl VarDecl{} = True
isDecl _ = False
```

I left the variable generation part, where you turn a variable name into some more structured representation of a variable, up to you (since you said little about what you want the `Variable` type to look like). But a few examples: one might choose `Variable` to be some kind of mutable reference, and `GenVar` to be a suitable mutability monad; or alternately perhaps `Variable` is simply an `Integer` and `GenVar` is a supply monad.

Comment: Hmm. So I'm still rewriting the tree, but using higher order types so that each time I do so I get a tree with different annotations. I bet I can use type classes to reduce boilerplate by providing a set of default tree traversal functions, right? I quite like that. However, I'm afraid I'm going to have to spend some time deciphering your code --- I'm new to this and am still not comfortable with monads.